# How to start from a specific scroll position when using vue js vue-virtual-scroller plugin?

Tags: vue.js, scroll, virtual, scroller

I'm using Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller plugin on different tabs, how can i force vue-virtual-scroll to start from a specific scroll position programatically ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found 2 methods `scrollToPosition` and `scrollToItem` (not mentioned in the document) which is probably what you are looking for.

You can use `scrollToItem` on both `RecycleScroller` and `DynamicScroller` components.

For `scrollToPosition` can only use on `RecycleScroller` but you can get `RecycleScroller` component by `$ref` and use it anyway.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lquatzr/)

Comment: Thank you so much !!! How did you find it, it was just what i was looking for, i've been struggling for days ! And thank you for the example !

Comment: When using `scrollToItem` the resulting position might be a bit off. A workaround that worked for me is to set the `min-item-size` to only `1` (see https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/issues/696#issuecomment-1192588679 )

Answer (score 1):

## Use `getListenerTarget()`

Assuming you are talking about [Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller)

`scrollToPosition` and `scrollToItem` did not work for me so here's an alternative.

Us the [`getListenerTarget()`](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/src/components/RecycleScroller.vue#L493) method to get the dom element and then scroll using the native [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) method.

```js
export default {

  methods: {
    scrollIt() {
      let scroller = this.$refs.virtualScroller.getListenerTarget()
      scroller.scrollTop = 200
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- Options have been left out for brevity -->
<RecycleScroller ref="virtualScroller">
  <!-- ... -->
</RecycleScroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset` or `start` property : https://github.com/tangbc/vue-virtual-scroll-list#props-type

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was asking for another virtual scroll library.